# How can I search for XML nodes containing certain text?

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an XML document with multiple nested nodes in it. Its structure is not fixed. I want to filter the XML based on a value passed by the user. i.e if out of all 1000 nodes, if 5 nodes contain a value that starts with 'xyz', then I want to retrieve those 5 nodes.

I am trying to use LINQ to XML to achieve this as I could not find 'LIKK' kind of operator in xPath. What sort of query should I write in LINQ?

So far I was doing something like below:

```
        dim FilterString as string  = "abc"
        Dim doc = New XDocument(Linq.XElement.Parse(objXML.DocumentElement.OuterXml))

        Dim query = doc.Elements()
        query = From e In doc.Elements()
                Where e.Value.ToUpper.StartsWith(FilterString.ToUpper)
                Select e
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        For Each result In query
            sb.AppendLine(result)
        Next
```

Sample XML would be like this:

```
<root>
<node>
<p1>abcxys</p1>
<p2>anc</p2>
<c1>
   <c2>abcggh</c2>
   <c3>123</c3>
</c1>
</node>
</root>
```

I want root/node/p1 and root/node/c1/c2 as my result. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If they can be in any node then you are going to have to query every node, there's nothing to filter by. This could be a very expensive process.

```
string userInput = "abc";

var xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Test\Xml.xml");
var q = from e in xDoc.Descendants()
             where e.Value.IndexOf(userInput) == 1
             select e;
```

If you want to test just the first part of the string you will still have to return the whole value and test the string against your condition.
This query checks to see if the text "abc" occurs the start of the string (Will return 0 for an empty string) and will return a collection of elements that need that condition.